# RavenDB Embedded: Where is the data stored on disk?

Tags: c#, ravendb, embedded-database

When using the **EmbeddableDocumentStore** for RavenDB, ***where does the data get stored on disk***?

```
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { DataDirectory = "TestApp" };
```

Is there a correlation between **DataDirectory** and the disk-location?

**Update**: Used the latest build as of 2011-08-09. It's a **console-app**, so no ASP.NET directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The directory it will use is based on the current directory of the application, or the base directory, if you use ~ as the start

Comment: What do you mean? It writes to some folder and creates a file on the fly there?

Comment: I was running a Console-app, so the folder was in the /bin/Debug-folder. That explains it :P

Comment: I thought embeddableDocumentStores don't persist anything to the disk. It's all *in memory* .. ?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: not really... the embedded version saves data in the disk but there's a in memory variant you can use too.

Answer (score 1):

What build are you using? In build from about a month ago this setting was ignored and the default directory of "Data" was used.